# IP address banned due to Magento SPAM mails. Need solution for this

Tags: magento2, ip-address, spam

What happens after a website gets spammed like mine (17,000+ bounce back emails) and 170000+ fake users which means 170000 emails were sent out over a year. Now IP address seems banned by some big email providers considered SPAM.
I have some questions that need answers:

1. If we change the IP address will that be OK?
2. Or is the email address info@xxxxxx... also banned?
3. If we change both IP and email address are we OK, or is the actual domain considered "spammy" now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Ashwin!

First, you have to fix the spam problem. Add a honeypot or a captcha to all Forms. You can use Magento or modules like [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha/). This is the most important step! Solve the Spam problem, before you try to solve the blacklist problem.

If your Magento Website is save and not used to send spam mails, you can start to solve the blacklist problem. Visit [mail-tester.com](https://www.mail-tester.com/) and send an mail from magento to the mailaddress on mail-tester.com. Check the score. On the result page, you can see the problems with your mails. Maybe you have to fix multiple things and delist your Mailaddress from multiple Blacklists. But trust me, it's possible. One of our customer had the same problem as you have. The rating on mail-tester.com was very bad. Today after some fixes (add captchas, add SPF and DKIM, delisting on some Blacklists) we have a score of 10/10 on mail-tester.com.

Comment: Hi Philippe, Thank you for the answer I appreciate it. I will try this and see.